# Can imported symbols from a module be inlined? And what about templates?

Tags: c++

So I just watched `CppCon 2015: Gabriel Dos Reis “Large Scale C++ with Modules: What You Should Know"` [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwdQA0pGWa4) and maybe I've missed it but can imported symbols from a module get inlined - like in LTO (and also - without the 3x slowdown in build time of LTO)?

And also can templates be exported from a module or will all templated code remain in header files?

Comment: Isn't it all more or less a wishful thinking at this point? So I guess the question 'how fast it is going to be' is rather moot?

Comment: I think this should be know up-front - otherwise depending on it's speed I will consider it's adoption

Comment: You will know when (if) you see it. The fact that the presentation of modules in C++ spent good third of it's time talking about dangers of macros is a good indication that the actual feature is nowhere. We will know how fast we will be travelling between the stars when we travel between the stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GabrielDosReis 17 days ago

No, the module proposal does not require LTO or LTCG or any technology of that sort.
In the module design paper, it is explicitly called out that a program that uses module should not its runtime performance decreased.
An exported inline function must be defined in the module interface unit. Same for exported templates.

from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4cbd3o/questions_about_the_modules_proposal/)